# Genetic algorithms on Titanic data set - overfitting or the real deal?

Tags: machine-learning, genetic-algorithms

As you're likely aware, predicting survivors from the Titanic disaster has been turned into an educational data science challenge on [Kaggle.com](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic). A few "competitors" have perfect scores, presumably due to using actual historical records. Whatever.

But then there is a tier of competitors with scores hovering around 88% accuracy. The posted solutions in this range all seem to be based on the use of **genetic algorithms**. Below is a small fraction of one of the [genetic algorithm scripts](https://www.kaggle.com/gwwang/genetic-programming-lb-0-88/code):

```
def GeneticFunction(data):
    return ((np.minimum( ((((0.058823499828577 + data["Sex"]) - np.cos((data["Pclass"] / 2.0))) * 2.0)),  ((0.885868))) * 2.0) +
            np.maximum( ((data["SibSp"] - 2.409090042114258)),  ( -(np.minimum( (data["Sex"]),  (np.sin(data["Parch"]))) * data["Pclass"]))) +
            (0.138462007045746 * ((np.minimum( (data["Sex"]),  (((data["Parch"] / 2.0) / 2.0))) * data["Age"]) - data["Cabin"])) +
            np.minimum( ((np.sin((data["Parch"] * ((data["Fare"] - 0.720430016517639) * 2.0))) * 2.0)),  ((data["SibSp"] / 2.0))) +
            np.maximum( (np.minimum( ( -np.cos(data["Embarked"])),  (0.138462007045746))),  (np.sin(((data["Cabin"] - data["Fare"]) * 2.0)))) +
            -np.minimum( ((((data["Age"] * data["Parch"]) * data["Embarked"]) + data["Parch"])),  (np.sin(data["Pclass"]))) +
            np.minimum( (data["Sex"]),  ((np.sin( -(data["Fare"] * np.cos((data["Fare"] * 1.630429983139038)))) / 2.0))) +
            np.minimum( ((0.230145)),  (np.sin(np.minimum( (((67.0 / 2.0) * np.sin(data["Fare"]))),  (0.31830988618379069))))) +
... [ + another 40 lines or so ]
```

I don't know much at all about genetic algorithms, but the Titanic data set isn't exactly ImageNet in terms of its complexity. There aren't that many rows and only a handful of features, and I have my suspicions that there is overfitting going on despite a good score on the test set.

*Are genetic algorithms really this good for predicting survivors in the Titanic data set?*

*If so, how do I build my own monstrosity like the one above?*